# How to use multiselect drop down in angular 6?

Tags: angular, angular6, npm-package

I want to use multiselect drop down, to achieve this I have installed the angular2 multiselect drop down by the command

```
npm install angular2-multiselect-dropdown --save
```

also imported in app.module.ts as

`import { AngularMultiSelectModule } from 'angular2-multiselect-dropdown/angular2-multiselect-dropdown';`

also included in as **AngularMultiSelectModule** in imports array.

But It's throwing error as

```
ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'angular2-multiselect dropdown/angular2-multiselect-dropdown' in 'D:\Works\frontend\src\app'
```

If anybody knows the solution please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

you need to mention AngularMultiSelectModule import in your imports section which is in
 `app.module.ts`
it will contain a library import as below 
`import { AngularMultiSelectModule } from 'angular2-multiselect-dropdown';`

Comment: try to highlight the keywords and be clear with the format it will help to reach out your answer for others

Answer (score 2):

You need to use this in module

```
import { AngularMultiSelectModule } from 'angular2-multiselect-dropdown';
```

they changed it in recent versions so this

`import { AngularMultiSelectModule } from 'angular2-multiselect-dropdown/angular2-multiselect-dropdown';` thorws an error

Answer (score 1):

This repository has not been maintained since over 1 year ago. I think this is an incompatibility with Angular 6.

Maybe try out this on, if it suits your needs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-multiselect-dropdown